# Maximize $\mbox{tr} (AX)$ subject to $\mbox{tr} (BX'CX) = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, qclp

Suppose $A,B,C$ are given square matrices and $X$ is a matrix variable. Is there a nice way to express the following?

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \mbox{tr} (AX)\\ \text{subject to} & \mbox{tr} (BX'CX) = 1\end{array}$$

Comment: what is $X'$? The transposed matrix?

Comment: Is your question in connection with some part of statistics, for example as can be seen in the Google book "Elliptically Contoured Models in Statistics
(Gupta, Varga") (around page 108) or in the paper (http://masseyblogs.ac.nz/jhunter/files/2013/10/4.RLIMS_Rao.pdf) ?

Comment: Are any of the matrices positive semidefinite?

Comment: I have only arrived at computing the gradients $\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}=A^\top$ and $\frac{\partial G}{\partial X}=CXB+C^\top XB^\top$.

Comment: @MiguelAtencia I doubt you compute $\nabla G$ correctly. since if you comute matrices inside of trac(..), it doesn't effect on trace, so its gradient!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: This is a NLP with one constraint so LID CQ holds. Let $D=BC$.

Take $f(X)=tr(AX)$ and $G(X)=tr(BX'CX)= tr(BCX'X)=tr(DX'X)$ Now calculate the gradient of $F$ and $G$, for example $\nabla F(X) = A^T$, set KKT conditions, it gives you necessary optimality condition: $X$ is optimal then $G(X)=1$ and $$A = \lambda \nabla G(X) $$

for some scalar $\lambda \in R$.

Comment: IMHO acronyms should be avoided if the answer is targeted at a wide audience.

Comment: I agree with Miguel Atencia : " NLP with one constraint so LID CQ holds" is SMS style... received as "not for dummies"...